# Estimated remaining battery time / Charging time left

Tags: android, battery, batterymanager

I was trying to figure out the way to calculate the Estimated remaining battery time of battery and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446460/get-how-much-time-i-have-before-the-battery-goes-to-0-android) did help me to do so but it isn't much accurate as the Android OS shows in: Settings > Battery option. Is there any way to pull out that approx. remaining battery timing / charging time left through Android's Internal function or Reflection?

Pic for reference:
[Estimated remaining battery time - Red outlined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYQzX.jpg)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Remaining battery time left is never going to be accurate-  it depends on usage patterns.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, I know that. But can we get that remaining time estimation that android shows by any means?